# Magento 1.9 Multiselection fields are all empty in the backend configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, backend

I have a problem with Magento's backend.
In Configuration, each multiselection field is empty, all options are no longer available. This problem is only in the configuration. Why?

I've already tried cleaning the cache and doing the reindex.

Any solution?
Thank you

This is the situation:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to logout/login ? Have you any error in your log files ?

Comment: Hi, any error when i try to logout/login...

Comment: have you made any changes recently or installed any extension?

Comment: By each multiselection do you mean each currency dropdown or other dropdown (under other tabs) as well?

Comment: I created a new store in "manage store" with the website, store and store view. For store view i edited from database, I did the same procedure I always did. Does the problem depend on this?

Comment: Any multiselection in configuration is empty.

Comment: Not sure problem depend on this or not but you should never add direct entry to database

Comment: revert your changes in database and then check

Comment: Any success. I deleted the string of store view that I entered into the database but the result is the same. What else can I do?

Comment: if you have backup of database, replace it with current database

Comment: Is the only solution?? If it is not a problem of database why should I back up? How can I debug this case? Thanks

Comment: you can check the recently edited code file for  this, by the way in configuration  currency dropdown values come from here - `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Currency.php` and the list of currencies is declared here `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale/Config.php`

Comment: I tried to check it but it's all ok. The problem is present on each field for multiselection of the configuration, not just for currency set up. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: I update my question with another screen for to fully show how the problem is present on all multiselection fields

Comment: can you add the steps of the changes you made , after which this dropdown values disappeared?

Comment: Hi, maybe I understand the problem. I found in the user section many fake users. I have already changed all the backend and database passwords. Is possible that this users have deleted all the fields in configuration? In this case how can I re-import ONLY these fields into the database?

Comment: However, the procedure I did today was this:

- Creating a new website
- Create new store
- Inserting a new string for the "store view" through the database

After that I went into the configuration and the fields were disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fold this solution

I looked at my file /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config

and matched it with original version

I was missing this line 463

here's a bigger chunk of the code to see full view the bolded area was missing from my file. I added it from original and it fixed it.

```
                if ($method) {
                    if ($fieldType == 'multiselect') {
                        $optionArray = $sourceModel->$method();
                    } else {
                        $optionArray = array();
                        foreach ($sourceModel->$method() as $value => $label) {
                            $optionArray[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
                }
                $field->setValues($optionArray);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```